# bash or something else: updating configuration files programmatically?

Tags: bash, archlinux, rc, daemons

What's the best approach to update an `/etc/rc.conf` configuration file **programmatically**?

Specifically, on an arch linux machine, I want to be able to programmatically update

```
DAEMONS=(syslog-ng network sshd ntpd netfs crond)
```

to

```
DAEMONS=(syslog-ng network sshd ntpd netfs crond postgresql)
```

after postgresql is successfully installed via `pacman`.

I presume I can write a function that does something like:

```
line="DAEMONS=(syslog-ng network sshd ntpd netfs crond)"

sed -i "/${line}/ s/)/ postgresql)/" /etc/rc.conf
```

specifically to handle this postgresql scenario.

However, going one step further, is there a more **generic way** (using a library if there's one you can recommend) that programmatically includes my service (such as `memcached`, or like a task server like `zeromq` etc) in the `DAEMONS` parameter in my `/etc/rc.conf` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't know about a generic way (there seems to be very few tools which do any parsing and modification of shell code), but one way to update a simple array like this one could be to actually read it, change it, then write back the whole line - Something like this:

```
source /etc/rc.conf
DAEMONS+=(postgresql)
sed -i -e s/'^DAEMONS=.*'/"DAEMONS=(${DAEMONS[@]})"/ /etc/rc.conf
```

Comment: Someone on #archlinux irc channel recommends `systemd` - https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd  Am reading up and experimenting on it at the moment.

Comment: `systemd` usage on a linode server instance requires that I use a custom kernel with `pv-grub` so a bash script is a simpler approach if I don't want to load up a custom kernel with `pv-grub`.